# Launch directions from Android Wear app

Tags: android, google-maps, wear-os

Hi Android developers,

Google Maps Micro (Maps for Android Wear) does not work like the Google Maps for smartphone. The app just crashes when using the classic intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=48.649469,-2.02579"));
startActivity(intent);
```

So, how to start directions from an Android Wear app?

Julien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the following intent :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("google.navigation:///?q=48.649469,-2.02579&mode=w"));
startActivity(intent);
```

- q=48.649469,-2.02579 : Saint-Malo latitude and longitude
- mode=w : walking

Other modes available are :

- d for driving
- r for public transportations
- b for bicycling